# Magento2 : Display Review Form any where in Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, review, product-review, product-detail-page

How to display Review form in any where in product page using new .phtml file?

Comment: You need to tell us exact place

Comment: yes , as i am creating configurable product page with first remove all  and make one configurable.phtml file in my theme so i need to display that any where that only review form.

Comment: Do you mean your custom configurable product page?

Comment: yes i created for my self so anyway i will display. thanks sir

Comment: Okay, can you please add here your layout xml code here.

Comment: how can i put code in comment sir, i am new for stack.

Comment: You can edit your Question, not in the comment. Edit your Question and add the code.

Comment: please check sir i added code below and i add that page in my custome theme.

Answer (score 0):

Please call Review-Form file Inside `catalog_product_view.xml`

> **\app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\theme-custom\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
</block>
```

Comment: thanks sir but i think this is something different what i want.

Answer (score 0):

in list page you can use

```
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }

<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

And Product Detail page You can use

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Comment: I want to show review form not a review list sir.

Comment: by the way thanks sir

Comment: Have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body><referenceContainer name="content">
        <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="college" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/type/configurable.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body></page>
```

Comment: Sorry, you can edit your question.

Comment: its ok sir please check anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

Replace your code with my code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="college" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/type/configurable.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: not working as form will goes hidden any way sir thanks i will do other ways